# Ion-select ng-model - display dynamic data on page load - Ionic 3/Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am having an issue with ionic's ion-select. I am trying to display the data value on the page load coming from the ng model. When I select an option I'm getting back all of the values for the ng model.

When I load the page I want the value to display initially. This should have been simple but am not sure. Thanks.

HTML

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="model" formControlName="data">
              <ion-option *ngFor="let person of people" value="person.personID">{{person.description}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-item>
```

TS

```
model: string = ''

ngOnInit(){

this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      data: '',
    })

this.userService.getUser(userId).subscribe(res => {
      this.people = res
      this.people.forEach(person => {
         if(person.type == 'someTypeId'){
           this.model = person.personID
         }
      })
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set "value" attribute. At least I created this snippet below and without "value" binding - mine also skipped to show default person...

ngModel needs to be initially bound to a value (I did directly to first item in the people array). Then once you do the selections it will get updated thanks to 2 way data binding.

```js
// example source:
public people: Array < any > = [{
    personID: "001",
    description: "first person"
  },
  {
    personID: "002",
    description: "second person"
  },
]
```

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Person</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="people[0].personID">
    <ion-option [value]="person.personID" *ngFor="let person of people">{{person.description}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```